# Gerar uma tabela a partir de outras 5

Tags: mysql, join

Preciso de uma ajuda pra construir uma query que traga dados de outras 5 tabelas.
Vou tentar ser o mais claro possível, caso falte informação, por favor me informem.

Vamos lá:

Tenho a tabela Midias:
http://jotacomdigital.com.br/imgs/midias.png

e a tabela Propostas:
http://jotacomdigital.com.br/imgs/propostas.png

As outras 3 tabelas é tranquilo, pois preciso apenas trazer um campo, não precisando de somas nem qualquer outra função.

O resultado deve ser esse:

http://jotacomdigital.com.br/imgs/resultado.png

Minha query Atual é essa:

```
    SELECT
       data_proposta,
       propostas.source_code,
       sum(midias.custo) as custo,
       COUNT(data_proposta) AS propostas,
       SUM(if(precog_FK <> 9, 1, 0)) AS validas
    FROM propostas
    LEFT JOIN midias
      ON `data_proposta` = `midias`.`data`
    GROUP BY data_proposta
```

Estou com problemas quando o tenho que fazer as somas dos custos da tabela mídias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alterei a query, ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT
    m.data,
    date_format(m.data,'%d-%m-%Y') AS mdata,
    m.midia_origem,
    p.source_code,
    m.campanha,
    COUNT(m.campanha) AS propostas,
    SUM(m.custo) as custo
FROM 
    propostas p
LEFT JOIN
    midias m
    ON m.source_code = p.source_code
GROUP BY
    mdata,m.campanha
ORDER BY 
    mdata ASC, m.source_code ASC
```

Agora não entendi a necessidade do seguinte código:

> SUM(if(precog_FK <> 9, 1, 0)) AS validas

Se na tabela "propostas" o código "souce_code" é único, o SUM não faz sentido, será sempre 1 ou 0 porque só existe um registo.

Outro tópico importante é criar índices para optimizar a consulta. Na tabela "midias" crie o índice na seguinte ordem: source_code,data,campanha

E na tabela "proposta" crie o índice sobre a coluna "source_code".

Comment: @Felipe eu fiz um teste e não deu muito certo. Alterei a query para isso: SELECT
   date_format(a.data_proposta,'%d-%m-%Y') AS data1,
   date_format(b.data,'%d-%m-%Y') AS data2,
   a.source_code,
   sum(b.custo) AS custo,
   COUNT(a.data_proposta) AS propostas,
   SUM(if(a.precog_FK <> 9, 1, 0)) AS validas
FROM propostas a, midias b
LEFT JOIN midias
  ON data1 = data2
GROUP BY data_proposta
está apresentando o erro #1054 - Unknown column 'data1' in 'on clause'

Comment: @DeBarros peço desculpas, me enganei. Alterei a query, coloquei "midas" e não "midias" no nome da tabela.

Comment: @Felipe, não rolou não man.

Comment: @DeBarros percebi errado o seu problema, estou a analisar melhor. Existe alguma ligação entre a tabela midias e propostas? algum id?

Comment: Nào existe um relacionamento declardo no banco, mas existe o codigo (source_code) que se repete nas tabelas e também as datas. Estou achando que o problema pode ser no SUM().

Comment: @DeBarros a coluna "source_code" é única na tabela de propostas?

Comment: Unica no sentido primarykey? Não. Ela pode se repetir. Mas se quer saber se na tabela propostas existe outro 'source_code', não.Não existe.

Comment: @DeBarros criei as tabelas aqui e alterei o post acima, veja se resolve o problema.

Comment: O precog_FK, quando diferente de 9 indica que é aprovado, então eu quero a quantidade dele. Por isso uso o SUM no precog_FK.

Comment: @DeBarros ok, percebo, porém se usar dessa forma a informação irá se repetir em todas as linhas, não seria melhor fazer uma query só para isso no lugar de fazer um SUM em todas linhas? Menos recursos consumidos na hora de executar a query. Essa nova query resolveu o problema?

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14284/discussion-between-debarros-and-filipe)